# How to deal with the eigenvalue constraints in optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Consider the following optimization problem w.r.t. $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underset{X}{\mathrm{minimize}}&~f(X)\\
\mathrm{subject~to}&~\rho(A - XB) \leq c,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\rho(\cdot)$ returns the spectral radius of a square matrix and $c > 0$.

How to deal with the constraint $\rho(A - XB) \leq c$? Thanks very much!

Comment: Tough one, its not even differentiable in general.

Comment: Not really serious here, but you could use Gelfand's formula and solve a series of problems $\|A-XB\|^k \le c^k$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks very much! Since $\rho(A - X B)^k \leq \|A - X B\|^k$ is a relaxation, we can design an iterative algorithm, starting from $k = 1$ and testing the feasibility of $\rho(A - X B) \leq c$, and then increase $k$ until the constraint is satisfied.

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be $\|(A-XB)^k\|$ so it is not very nice. I was not really serious, unless a small $k$ approximation was sufficient.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks very much for your help. I think $k = 1$ can be good enough :-)

Comment: The constraint can be entered in CVX (or similarly in other similar convex optimization tool) as `norm(A-X*B) <= c`. Whether the whole problem can be handled in such a tool depends on what `f` is.

Comment: What is the function $f$ here? This an important detail that has been omitted. Also, it would be interesting to know if $A$ and $B$ has some structure that could be exploited. Finally, some context is always important to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this answer based on the few information about the problem we have. I will update it when we get additional details.

From Lyapunov theory for linear systems, we know that $\rho(A-XB)\le c$ if and only if there exists a matrix $P\succ0$ (i.e. it is symmetric positive definite) such that

$$(A-XB)^TP(A-XB)-c^2P\preceq0\qquad \textrm{(i.e. negative semidefinite)}.$$

By virtue of the Schur complement, this is equivalent to saying that

$$\begin{bmatrix}-c^2P & (A-XB)^TP\\ P(A-XB) & -P\end{bmatrix}\preceq0.$$

Letting $U:=PX$ yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}-c^2P & A^T-B^TU^T\\ PA-UB & -P\end{bmatrix}\preceq0,$$

which is linear in the variables $P$ and $U$. This finally yields the equivalent optimization problem

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underset{P,U,X}{\mathrm{minimize}}&~f(X)\\
\mathrm{subject~to}&~\begin{bmatrix}-c^2P & A^T-B^TU^T\\ PA-UB & -P\end{bmatrix}\preceq0,\\
&~PX=U.
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

This is nonlinear optimization problem which may reduce to a convex one depending on the cost function $f$.

Comment: That is great! Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: @Ryan The point of the change of variable $U=PX$ is in the hope that you can transform the cost $f(X)$ into an equivalent cost $g(U)$, that can make the problem convex (an LMI problem). Otherwise, it is a BMI problem for which you will need to use heuristics.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind suggestions.

Comment: @Ryan If you have more context or details, do not hesitate to come back and ask.